# Ruby Shortest common superstring

Tags: ruby, algorithm

The goal of the shortest common superstring problem is to find the shortest
possible string that contains every string in a given set as substrings. I understand that the problem is "NP complete". But there are approximation strategies for the problem. 
Given short strings for example

```
ABRAC
ACADA
ADABR
DABRA
RACAD
```

How to implement the shortest common superstring problem such that the output for the given strings above is `ABRACADABRA`? 
Another example

```
Given

fegiach
bfgiak
hfdegi
iakhfd
fgiakhg
```

the string
`bfgiakhfdegiach` is a possible solution of length 15.

I would like to implement this in Ruby although I do not have an in depth study of algorithms, though am working to improve that.

A naive greedy implementation would involve creating a suffix array for each substring

```
def suffix_tree(string)
  size = string.length
  suffixes = Array.new(size)
  size.times do |i|
    suffixes[i] = string.slice(i, size)
  end
  suffixes
end

#store the suffixes in a hash
#key is a fragment, value = suffixes
def hash_of_suffixes(fragments)
  suffixes_hash = Hash.new
  fragments.each do |frag|
    suffixes_hash["#{frag}"]= suffix_tree(frag)
  end
  suffixes_hash
end


fragments = ['ABRAC','ACADA','ADABR','DABRA','RACAD']
h = hash_of_suffixes(fragments)

#then search each fragment in all the suffix trees and return the number of 
#overlaps for each key

#store the results in graph??
#find possible ordering of the fragments

I would be grateful with some help.
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Maybe genitic algorithm?

Comment: Both of your examples are wrong, shortest superstring for `['ABRAC', 'ACADA', 'ADABR', 'DABRA', 'RACAD']` is either `"RACADABRAC"` or `"ADABRACADA"`. And `"fegiach"`, and `"fgiakhg"` are not even in the string `"bfgiakhfdegiach"`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I may have been quick in this but you get my idea.. the shortest string that includes all the substrings.

Answer (score 1):

Please note the comment pointing out the problems with your examples. Also note that if there is some slick way to do this, I don't know what it is. I just iterate over all the permutations, smoosh them together, and find the shortest.

```
class ShortestSuperstring
  def initialize(*strings)
    self.strings = strings
  end

  def call
    @result ||= smoosh_many strings.permutation.min_by { |permutation| smoosh_many(permutation.dup).size }
  end

  private

  attr_accessor :strings

  def smoosh_many(permutation, current_word='')
    return current_word if permutation.empty?
    next_word = permutation.shift
    smoosh_many permutation, smoosh_two(current_word, next_word)
  end

  def smoosh_two(base, addition)
    return base if base.include? addition
    max_offset(base, addition).downto 0 do |offset|
      return base << addition[offset..-1] if addition.start_with? base[-offset, offset]
    end
  end

  def max_offset(string1, string2)
    min string1.size, string2.size
  end

  def min(n1, n2)
    n1 < n2 ? n1 : n2
  end
end
```

And test suite:

```
describe ShortestSuperstring do
  def self.ss(*strings, possible_results)
    example "#{strings.inspect} can come from superstrings #{possible_results.inspect}" do
      result = described_class.new(*strings).call
      strings.each { |string| result.should include string }
      possible_results.should include(result), "#{result.inspect} was not an expected superstring."
    end
  end

  ss '', ['']
  ss "a", "a", "a", ['a']
  ss "a", "b", %w[ab ba]
  ss 'ab', 'bc', ['abc']
  ss 'bc', 'ab', ['abc']
  ss 'abcd', 'ab', ['abcd']
  ss 'abcd', 'bc', ['abcd']
  ss 'abcd', 'cd', ['abcd']
  ss 'abcd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ['abcd']
  ss 'abcd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ab', 'cd', 'bcd', ['abcd']

  %w[ABRAC ACADA ADABR DABRA RACAD].permutation.each do |permutation|
    ss *permutation, %w[RACADABRAC ADABRACADA]
  end

  %w[fegiach bfgiak hfdegi iakhfd fgiakhg].permutation.each do |permutation|
    ss *permutation, %w[bfgiakhgiakhfdegifegiach
                        bfgiakhgfegiachiakhfdegi
                        iakhfdegibfgiakhgfegiach
                        iakhfdegibfgiakhgfegiach
                        fegiachiakhfdegibfgiakhg
                        fegiachbfgiakhgiakhfdegi
                        iakhfdegifegiachbfgiakhg]
  end
end
```